# Using two or more regions from a single profile in one AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config, aws-credentials

I face a recent problem these days with my AWS structure.
I have two accounts in AWS. One is the test environments and the other is the production.

The most cases i use aws cli to perform actions i want.

My setup:

- config

  ```
  [default]
  region=eu-central-1
  output=json

  [profile test]
  region=eu-central-1
  output=json

  [profile prod]
  region=eu-central-1
  output=json
  ```
- credentials

  ```
  [default]
  aws_access_key_id = AK_SOMETHING
  aws_secret_access_key = SAK_SOMETHING
  [test]
  role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<test_account>:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole
  source_profile = prod
  [prod]
  aws_access_key_id = <random_variable>
  aws_secret_access_key = <random_variable>
  aws_session_token = <random_variable>
  ```

Now, in account prod with profile 'prod', i add in region ap-south-1 an another structure.

How do you suggest so i can make it to access to it?

I tried to edit the 'config' file like this:

```
[default]
region=eu-central-1
output=json

[profile test]
region=eu-central-1
output=json

[profile prod]
region=eu-central-1
output=json
```

and i connect correctly to my mumbai region resources, but in the future, i will always have to make this edit to connect.